# Using an Assigned Variable to Dynamically Read/Store Data in R

Tags: r, assign

Is it possible to use an assigned variable as a data frame name and as a value?

Example:

```
#Assign date value
date_input <- 10032017
```

I would change this value each time I have a new file.

My original code:

```
eggs_prod_10032017 <- read_excel("filename", sheet="x_10032017", col_names = FALSE)
```

Is there a way I can incorporate the assigned variable in my code so it would be something like:
    eggs_prod_date_input <- read_excel("filename", sheet="x_date_input", col_names = FALSE)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try this:

```
assign(paste0("eggs_prod_",date_input),
       read_excel("filename", sheet=paste0("x_",date_input), col_names = FALSE))
```